# Enforce optional chain when accessing optional properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint, optional-chaining

I have a Typescript project, and I've found that when I access a property or function of a property that is optional, it doesn't error.

For example:

```js
type Example = {
    bar?: string[]
}

const foo: Example = {}

// No error, but the code will crash!
foo.bar.map(string => string.toUpperCase())
```

`bar` is an optional property, so `foo` being an empty object is completely valid. But Typescript doesn't complain that `foo.bar` might be undefined, and therefore `.map()` will result in `Cannot read properties of undefined`.

Is this something I can do with a eslint rule, or a compiler option? I want it to flag up the issue and require something like `foo.bar?.map()`, which would not fail.

Comment: go to tsconfig.json and set `strictNullChecks` to `true` or even better: set `strict` to `true`

Comment: @TobiasS. Ah, doh I'd disabled strict earlier to test a different thing. Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in comments: `strict: true` in tsconfig

Comment: @dippas: Why do you say that? This looks like an answer to me. It's elevating a suggested answer from the comments to the answers section, where it belongs.